# JavaScript setInterval: Changing the active div based on the given period of time

Tags: javascript

I have 6 images shown below. The first div contains 4 images and the remaining 2 images are placed to the 2nd div. Using my pagination in a form of a bullet.  What I`m trying to achieve is to automatically change the active div every 3secs. The only thing that comes to my mind is to use setInterval.

Here's the JavaScript Code

```
function showFrameIndex(index) {
var frames = document.getElementsByClassName('gall-frame');
var badges = document.getElementsByClassName('badge-item');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
frames[i].style.display = 'none';
}
frames[index].style.display = 'flex';

for (i = 0; i < badges.length; i++) {
badges[i].className = 'badge-item badge-item-inactive';
}
badges[index].className = 'badge-item';
}
var displayIndexFrame = 0;
showFrameIndex(displayIndexFrame);
```

Here's the current output

1st div
 [image]

2nd div
[image]

Comment: You just want to change the div periodically? SetInterval is the correct function to do that.

Comment: Alternative is using setTimeout() inside your function which calls same function. Did you even try setInterval?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the div periodically maybe 3secs

Comment: var i = -1; setInterval(function() { i++; i = i < divCount ? i : 0; hideAllDivs(); showDiv(i); }, time);

Comment: Is the divs one below the other as in the picture or next to each other ? Are both divs visible at all times ? when you say `change the active div` does that mean hide one and show the other ?  or put one above the other ? or scroll to the next one ?

Comment: No these 2 divs are not visible at the same time. Only 1 div shows based on the active bullet below. The first bullet is the 1st div the 2nd bullet is the 2nd div which contains the remaining images. what I want is to automatically change the active div within a period of time @Zohir Salak

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how you can hide something and show the other, i'm sure there's better ways, now inside the callback of `setInterval` you'll
have to add the code to change the bullets you have, Also if you only want this to happen once, change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`

```js
let d1 = document.querySelector('.d1');
let d2 = document.querySelector('.d2');
let timeinSec = 3;
setInterval(() => {
  d1.classList.toggle('hide');
  d2.classList.toggle('hide');
}, timeinSec * 1000);
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.d2 {
  background: orange;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1 hide"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```